# Power BI: Recommendation about Privacy problem

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, ssas

Scenario: In my company, we have an SSAS Multidimensional Cube, and the future Power BI reports will be hosted on internal Report Server on-premise( using Live Connection to connect SSAS Cube ). These reports will be embedded in an internal Web Portal through Iframe.

My problem is: External clients will access these Reports through the Web Portal. And the 'client A' cannot see the measures, filters, data, etc..of 'client B'.

I would like a path/technology recommendation so that I can study to solve this problem in an elegantly and correctly way.

Row Level Security passing the Client ID in the iframe URL would be a good alternative? Other alternative?

Thank You

Comment: You can apply a security model to SSAS MD, some details here http://bifuture.blogspot.com/2011/09/ssas-setup-dynamic-security-in-analysis.html you will need to create a MDX Assembly, that takes the username and filters the data. Another option is use a perspective for each client

Answer (score 0):

I would go this route,

> **Scenario 1:**

Let's say you have client A and it has different users (Executives, Managers, Analyst) then would you be sharing all data to all employee!!
You need to introduce a level reporting and then it filter through client ID and level access.

> **Scenario 2:**

You are just sharing it to certain people within client A which has same level access then RLS by client ID would do the job.

**There might have more user case and the solution is solely depend on case by case.**

I hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Mboolean. 
In my case all users in Client A will have the same privileges and access all data from Client A. The big problem is to hide data from Client B, C, D... in the report on iframe. Will not exist different level access.

When you say 'client ID', I would go pass the 'client ID' through the URL in Iframe?

Comment: You could pass the client ID in the URL to filter whole report but then you have to find a way to hide filter pane in your frame so no client see filter option to change filter condition. Also, Check for the newer version, I guess you can hide the filter by clicking hide on filter pane.